# Acer iconia tab A500 SipManager.isApiSupported returns false (Voip api not supported)

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, voip, sip

Tablet: Acer A500 GEN1
Android 3.1 kernel 2.6.36.3 (API level 12)

[SipManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/sip/SipManager.html) since API level 9

Nowhere in the device specs I could read, that there is no Voip support. Last week tested my application on Galaxy 10.1 tab and everything worked fine.

> **Here are the requirements for developing a SIP application:**
>
> You must have a mobile device that is running Android 2.3 or higher.
>
> SIP runs over a wireless data connection, so your device must have a data connection (with a mobile data service or Wi-Fi). This means that you can't test on AVD—you can only test on a physical device. For details, see Testing SIP Applications.
>
> Each participant in the application's communication session must have a SIP account. There are many different SIP providers that offer SIP accounts.

[Source](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/network/sip.html)

My device meets all the requirements.

**What the hell?**

Comment: For now I have figured out that the Asus has modified the OS, but I can't find any referenc that they have thrown out the SIP and VOIP functionality...any help guys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find the reference, but it seems to me that Acer has turned off the Voip support deliberately. I solved this problem by rooting my device and installing Galaxy Tab 10.1 ROM.

For help, see: http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=1136